# Angular - how to render webpage only on server without rendering it again in user browser

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

I want to use Angular to  prerender on server side during build many webpages based on my database but I don't want to rerender them again in user browser and load data from database again.

I know how to prerender during build but I don't know how to stop angular from destroying server content in user browser to replace it with the same content generated second time in user browser.

Comment: Use Angular Universal for SSR it already includes rehydration and cashing.

Comment: If you have all your requests runner again in browser, check setup of https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule#withservertransition

Comment: @izmaylovdev can you provide an example of this? I've similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75934163/angular-pre-rendered-without-ssr