# Angular: Pre Rendered without SSR

Tags: angular, nginx, prerender

In Angular 13 and what I usually do with apps when I want them in production is run something like `ng build -c production` in order to create a production build and then deploy over SFTP to a simple nginx webserver.

Now I'm exploring making small websites with angular and some level SEO is a concern. After reading https://angular.io/guide/universal I came to the conclusion that Angular provides both SSR and Pre-rendering.

After `npm run prerender` I get two folders:

- `project/dist/project/browser`
- `project/dist/project/server`

If I upload the contents of `browser` to my nginx server I seem to get a working application. It seems to load the pre-rendered HTML and then switch to a full Angular SPA like usual.

Multiple guides suggest that I should also deploy the `server` folder on a server with nodejs, have `ng run app-name:server` running and proxy pass nginx requests to that server.

**Question**: Is it "safe" to run without a server-side "server" doing SSR if my goal is just to have static HTML for crawlers? Can change my config to not build the "server" part / clean things up? How so?

My website seems to work fine without it, however even when the SPA is loaded the HTML contains references to the server like this:

[image]

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: It's should be save to use only browser build. As I know it contains all you need for static pages. But if you need to have some dynamic content (from API for example) its better to use full SSR.